# C# crop image to ellipse with edge blured

Tags: c#

I'm trying to crop an rectangular image to ellipse with blur on edges like this :

[resulting image has transparent edges (blended)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPvK.png)

can anyone help with this please 
this code work but doesn't give the transparency to the edges :

```
Image dstImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, srcImage.PixelFormat);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dstImage);
using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(backGround))
{
    g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
}
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

path.AddEllipse(30, 30, dstImage.Width-60, dstImage.Height-60);
g.SetClip(path);
g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This kind of transparency is not well supported in Winforms. One way to tackle it would be to draw a series of growing or shrinking ellipses to gradually fade out the image (to white). You would use a semittransparent pen for this..

Comment: Your idea works ... big thanks